# Bcryptjs always return false

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bcryptjs

> Hi, I am trying to use the *bcriptjs* library to compare the encrypted password with the database password.
> I am using the "compare" method.
> The values ​​that I add to the method are:
>
> - First, the password that the user gives me. (*password*)
> - Second, the encrypted password of the database. (*pass_db*)
>   But always return false

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const create = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (password.length < 6) {
    res.send({ msgType: "error", msg: "Contraseña almenos 6 caracteres" });
  } else {
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 6);

    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?,?)",
      [email, hash],
      (err) => {
        res.send({ msgType: "success", msg: "Usuario creado correctamente" });
      }
    );
  }
};

//TODO Login dont work always return false
const login = (req, res) => {

  //Password from req.body
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  db.query(
    "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ?",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
      // Password encrypted from database
      pass_db = result[0].password;

      if(err){
        res.send({msgType:'error', msg:'Incorrect Login'})
      }

      if(result.length > 0){
        
        //Compare password from req.body with password encryted from database
        const validate = bcrypt.compareSync(password, pass_db);

        //Always false
        console.log(validate);

        if(validate){
          res.send({msgType:'success', msg: "Correct login" })
        }else{
          res.send({msgType:'error', msg: "Incorrect email or password" });
        }
      }else{
        res.send({msgType:'error', msg: "Incorrect email or password" });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I tried this code too but didn't work eighter.

```
bcrypt.hash(password, 6, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        bcrypt.compare(pass_db, hash, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(result);
        });
      });
```

I hope you can help with this problem, thanks.

Comment: if its `require('bcrytpjs')` its wrong it should be `require('bcryptjs')`, other than that have you checked pass_db and password are expected values, perhaps you should validate that they are even set, what happens if email not found, server crash?

Comment: is your encrypted/hashed password in the database created using bcrypt and follows this format? https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info

Comment: it's best if you edit your question to include that (better formatting and others will see it right away)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
I have added the create method and you can see how I save the data _(email, hash)_

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the password being stored in the db is retrieved properly it should work. I simplified the program to not use a database (just a local object to store the hashed password) and it works fine.  Since I'm using the same `bcrypt` commands you are, the only thing I can imagine is that there's a problem with the hashed password not coming back from the database properly.  Try printing out the hashed value during `create` and again after retrieving from the db and confirm they match. If `pass_db` is not exactly what it should be, that would explain why you can't compare successfully. Are you positive that `result[0]` coming back from the `db.query` is a JSON object that has a `password` attribute?

Here's my simplified version of the code that works without using the db:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const passwords = {};

const create = async (email, password) => {
  if (password.length < 6) {
    console.log("Password must be at least 6 characters");
  } else {
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 6);
    passwords[email] = hash;  // Store the hash in the passwords instead of db
  }
};

const login = (email, password) => {
  const pass_db = passwords[email];  // Retrieve hash from passwords instead of db
  if (pass_db) {
    const validate = bcrypt.compareSync(password, pass_db);
    if (validate) {
      console.log('Correct login');
    } else {
      console.log('Incorrect email or password');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Incorrect email or password');
  }
};

const email = 'abc@mail.com';
const pw = 'testpass12345';
create(email, pw);
console.log('Try the right password');
login(email, pw);
console.log('Try the wrong password');
login(email, 'wrongpw');
console.log('Try the wrong email');
login('unknown@abc.com', 'blah');
```

Running this program gives the following output:

```
Try the right password
Correct login
Try the wrong password
Incorrect email or password
Try the wrong email
Incorrect email or password
```